# How to compare two dates in text boxes?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to compare two dates in text boxes.

```vb
Public Function CourseStatus(ByVal RefDate2 As Variant) As String

    Dim Description As String   
     
    If Len(RefDate2) > 0 And IsDate(RefDate2) Then

        Select Case DateDiff("d", Date, RefDate2)
            Case Is > 60
                CourseStatus = "In Date"
            Case Is > 0
                CourseStatus = "Expiring"
            Case Is = [ParticipationDate]
                CourseStatus = "Not Refreshed"
            Case Else
                CourseStatus = "Expired"
        End Select        
    Else
        CourseStatus = "Please Book"
    End If
        
End Function
```

If `[ParticipationDate]` & `[RefDate2]` match return "Not Refreshed" as CourseStatus.

I need to do this before running the rest of the code to give "in Date" "Expiring" "Expired" and if none of this applies display "Please Book".

e.g
ParticipationDate 1/1/19
RefDate2 1/1/19
CourseStatus "Not Refreshed"

Comment: Your code looks okay at first glance, so what is your question ?

Comment: Case Is = [ParticipationDate]
            CourseStatus = "Not Refreshed"

This part doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didn't read your code super accurately.
Your datediff function returns a integer value not a date. You should use

```
Case is 0
```

to check for a date match.

Comment: Case is = 0 doesnt appear to work. 

I have some test data

part date = 16/01/1919
Ref Date = 16/01/2019
Status = Not Refreshed

Comment: I need it to run this part of the code before comparing the date

Comment: That would be correct the date diff between 16/01/1919 and 16/01/2019 isn't 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

You might use something like this:

```
If Len(RefDate2) > 0 And IsDate(RefDate2) Then

    Select Case DateDiff("d", Date, RefDate2)
        Case Is > 60
            CourseStatus = "In Date"
        Case Is > 0
            CourseStatus = "Expiring"
        Case Else
            If DateDiff("d", RefDate2, [ParticipationDate]) = 0 Then
                CourseStatus = "Not Refreshed"
            Else
                CourseStatus = "Expired"
            End If
    End Select        
Else
    CourseStatus = "Please Book"
End If
```